# Delete records from Table A If no records have been created yet in Table B

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have an MS Access database where users go through 6 forms to fill out the initial contact information.

I'm looking to delete orphan rows from Table A if no records have been created yet in Table B with the same Foreign Key of ID for both table.

I'm hoping to keep data integrity if the user doesn't completely fill out all the forms and remove only partly finished entries.

Comment: You should look at table relationships and referential integrity rules. They'll take care of that for you. This type of query you're describing should only be used to do an initial cleanup of the database

Comment: @dbmitch … FYI, I do have the relationship setup between the tables based on the field ID. What Aureate wrote is what I needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
Delete TableA.*
From TableA
Where NOT Exists( Select 1 
From TableB 
Where TableB.Name = TableA.Name )
```